# ViewPager not called recyclerViewAdapter again

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have main fragment, inside main fragment I have `ViewPager`. this view pager loaded 2 fragments, Inside each pager there is a Recycler View and implementation of Recycler Viewadapter:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerAdapter = new UsersRecyclerAdapter(getContext());
    suserList = Collections.emptyList();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    recyclerAdapter.setItems(paginator.generatePage(currentPage));
```

this RecyclerView shows a list of stuff from service. my question is for the first time `setItems` method works and the list is shown into RecyclerView, but when `paginator.generatePage(currentPage)` generate the new list of data, my RecyclerView does not show new data?

this is method at my Recycler Viewadapter:

```
public void setItems(List<Suser> items) {
    if (items == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot set `null` item to the Recycler adapter");
    susers.clear();
    susers.addAll(items);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

seems my fragment that loaded inside ViewPager is not refresh again and this `recyclerAdapter.setItems(paginator.generatePage(currentPage));` not called again.
what is your suggest?

**************Edit*************

I have changed the main Fragment to an Activity.then I have created a callback into my Activity and finally, I have implemented this callback to fragment and have called `notifyDataSetChanged` but the list of Recycler View is no changed??

```
@Override
public void onLoad() {
    recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Recycler View still represent one page at first!!

Comment: if you use your methods in onstart override it will keep refresh

Comment: @HemalHerath.no i am not using any method. how could i use ?

Comment: can u please tell me why u set recyclerview in onResume method

Comment: there is no reason. but i am using eventbus and I register event bus in onCreateView. @HemalHerath

Comment: @HemalHerath plz tell me about refresh method.

Comment: you can use adapter.update("what u add");

Comment: Add your entire ViewPager code, How you are refreshing your fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Change OnResume to OnStart override method and 
In Adapter code, try the following changes..

```
public void update(ArrayList<Person> data) {
mData.clear();
mData.addAll(data)
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I have this method with different name: `setItems`.
 
@HemalHerath

Comment: nothing is changed .this is my fragment http://codepad.org/CpptIokz  my Adapter http://codepad.org/tvIPxz21  @HemalHerath